# How to be certain that functions in my cpu emulator are not running in parallel?

Tags: c

I've been writing an arcade game emulator in C using SDL and have run into a weird problem with emulating systems with multiple cpus. I've got something like this:

```
int done = 0;
int outputDebug = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("debug_output.txt", "w");

while (!done)
{

  // Run one instruction on cpu #1
  emulate(cpu1);

  if (outputDebug)
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d \n", cpu1->variable1, cpu1->variable2);

  // Run one instruction on cpu #2
  emulate(cpu2);

  // pressing a key in here toggles outputDebug
  checkInput();
}
```

Now here's what's weird...if I comment out the if statement which should have absolutely no bearing on the emulate functions, some bugs go away, and other bugs surface. If I add in some other inconsequential code, like a call to SDL_GetTicks() for example, I'll get yet a different set of bugs. I've reproduced this several times. It is always exactly the same bugs for each variation.

The conclusion I've come to is that the two calls to the emulate function must be getting run in parallel and having other code in there causes them to get out of sync to a greater or lesser degree which breaks the emulation in different ways. I'm using the GNU C compiler and not passing any optimization arguments...I tried passing -O0 even though that's the default, and everything behaves the same way.

I'm on Windows 7, using the GNU compiler as mentioned, and SDL is the only external library I'm using.

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Basically if *emulate(x)* does not do any threading or forking, you're likely have a UB somewhere (stack / memory / pointer / array overflow ... problem). Maybe try to emulate only on one cpu?

Comment: @racraman is exactly right. When behavior changes by adding and removing function calls, it almost certainly means some other code is reading stack locations that are uninitialized. The code you're adding and removing causes that memory to be left with different values. Another possibility is that you're writing outside an array on the stack, and the area that's trashed is moving around, causing other code to display different, buggy behavior.  Consider using `valgrind` or another memory usage debugging framework to find your faulty code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that somewhere in your emulate functions, you're referencing uninitialised memory - eg :

```
void somefunction(char *somearg)
{
    static char *myvar;

    if (somecondition) {
        myvar = somearg;
    }

    // Now do something with myvar
```

If somecondition is true first time through, then myvar would be set to an address in the process' memory space.

If somecondition is subsequently false, then myvar will be left still pointing to that same address - which is still in the processes' memory space (so wouldn't necessarily cause a failure) but not what you're expecting (hence the 'bug's).

The left-over contents of that particular address in memory could well have changed depending on the calling stack - eg. it might well be pointing to an address that happened to have been used by that "fprintf" (hence one "set of bugs").  If outputDebug is false, then that memory address might last have been used by some other function (hence a different "set of bugs").

Of course, this is all speculation (since the code you've presented looks fine), but is just an example of the sort of things that could cause the symptoms you've described, and what to possibly look for.

Comment: Thanks racraman! This was pretty much exactly my problem. Downloaded and installed Dr. Memory and it picked this off right away.